# How to post product in amazon MWS?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

Im using amazon MWS feed API to post a product in amazon, but this is not happening and im getting error like this..

Some attributes are missing for SKU: [*****************].For more details, see http://sellercentral.amazon.in/gp/errorcode/8058

This is the xml im submitting. Please can any one answer to my question here only, thanx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
 <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
 <Header>
   <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
   <MerchantIdentifier>********</MerchantIdentifier>
 </Header>
 <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
 <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
 <Message>
  <MessageID>1</MessageID>
  <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
  <Product>
   <SKU>98765654356765498776565GTRF546</SKU>
   <StandardProductID>
    <Type>EAN</Type>
    <Value>45201187656</Value>
   </StandardProductID>
   <ProductTaxCode>A_TOY_GENERALL</ProductTaxCode>
   <Condition>
    <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
   </Condition>
   <NumberOfItems>10</NumberOfItems>
   <DescriptionData>
    <Title>Smartivity EDGE Jurassic Wonders Pack With Many Features </Title>
    <Brand>Smartivity</Brand>
    <Description>Smartivity EDGE LET’S LEARN and play 1,2,3… set includes 10</Description>
    <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 1</BulletPoint>
    <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 2</BulletPoint>
    <MSRP currency="INR">410</MSRP>
    <Manufacturer>Smartivity Labss Pvt. Ltd.</Manufacturer>
    <MfrPartNumber>SMRT1025</MfrPartNumber>
    <ItemType>toy-figures</ItemType>
    <TargetAudience>Children</TargetAudience>
    <TargetAudience>unisex-adult</TargetAudience>
    <RecommendedBrowseNode>1350381031</RecommendedBrowseNode>
   </DescriptionData>
   <ProductData>
    <Toys>
     <ProductType>
      <ToysAndGames>
       <Color>Blue</Color>
       <ColorMap>Brown</ColorMap>
      </ToysAndGames>
     </ProductType>
     <AgeRecommendation>
      <MinimumManufacturerAgeRecommended unitOfMeasure="years">5</MinimumManufacturerAgeRecommended>
     </AgeRecommendation>
   </Toys>
  </ProductData>
 </Product>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi you need to add price and quantity for the product to complete.
Try these two XML.

```
 <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>*********</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Price</MessageType>
    <Message>                         
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>       bnm
    <Price>
    <SKU>UNIQUE-ME-87895656587</SKU>
    <StandardPrice currency="INR">500</StandardPrice>
    </Price>
    </Message>
    </AmazonEnvelope>       


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>***********</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Inventory</MessageType>
    <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Inventory>
    <SKU>UNIQUE-ME-87895656587</SKU>
    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    </Inventory>
    </Message>
    </AmazonEnvelope>
```